# How to keep random numbers from changing in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, random-number-generator

I am trying to generate a set list of random numbers between 1 and 5 using the `RANDBETWEEN` formula.

I'm running into a problem that every time I click another cell anywhere in the sheet or even open and close the sheet after saving it, the random numbers change again. How can I keep the random numbers from changing?

Comment: I don't have Excel installed, and thus can't test this but you should find what you want [here](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/stupid-random-numbers-keep-recalculating/). In option 3 he creates his own function which mimics RAND and RANDBETWEEN, but removes the volatility that comes with those functions.

Answer (score 12):

Copy the range and insert at the same position. After inserting, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and select the option to only keep actual values from the menu that opens.

Comment: Shortcuts to do this: Select the range with randoms, press `Ctrl+C`, press `Shift+F10`, press `V`

Answer (score 6):

[RANDBETWEEN()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/randbetween-HP005209230.aspx) is regenerated *every time the sheet is calculated* so the only way to keep the random values **persistent** is to turn off automatic calculations or to copy the *values* that are generated and store them.

You can either overwrite where they were calculated or place them in another location by *copying* and *paste special - values*.

Answer (score 3):

MS has explained the way to do this in [RAND function's documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rand-function-4cbfa695-8869-4788-8d90-021ea9f5be73)

> - To generate a random real number between a and b, use:
>
>   ```
>     =RAND()*(b-a)+a
>   ```
> - If you want to use RAND to generate a random number but don't want the numbers to change every time the cell is calculated, you can enter `=RAND()` in the formula bar, and then press <kbd>F9</kbd> to change the formula to a random number. The formula will calculate and leave you with just a value.

So you can enter `=RAND()*(b-a)+a` or `=RANDBETWEEN(a, b)` then **press <kbd>F9</kbd>** to replace the formula with its result

## See also

- [How do I "Freeze" the numbers given by RANDBETWEEN?](https://support.office.com/en-us/community?threadid=6e488bdc-fafd-4e1c-bab2-578567533da4)